# How to allow airflow dags for concrete user(s) only

Tags: airflow

The problem is pretty simple. I need to limit airflow web users to see and execute only certain DAGs and tasks.

If possible, I'd prefer not to use [Kerberos](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html#kerberos) nor [OAuth](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html#oauth-authentication).

The [Multi-tenancy](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html#multi-tenancy) option seems like an option to go, but couldn't make it work the way I expect.
My current setup:

- added airflow web users `test` and `ikar` via [Web Authentication / Password](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html#password)
- my unix username is `ikar` with a home in `/home/ikar`
- no `test` unix user
- airflow `1.8.2` is installed in `/home/ikar/airflow`
- added two DAGs with one task:

  - one with `owner` set to `ikar`
  - one with `owner` set to `test`
- `cat airflow.cfg`:

```ini
[core]
# The home folder for airflow, default is ~/airflow
airflow_home = /home/ikar/airflow

# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository
# This path must be absolute
dags_folder = /home/ikar/airflow-test/dags

# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /home/ikar/airflow/logs

# Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage. Users
# must supply a remote location URL (starting with either 's3://...' or
# 'gs://...') and an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
# location.
remote_base_log_folder =
remote_log_conn_id =
# Use server-side encryption for logs stored in S3
encrypt_s3_logs = False                                                                                                                                                                  
# DEPRECATED option for remote log storage, use remote_base_log_folder instead!                                                                                                          
s3_log_folder =                                                                                                                                                                          

# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include                                                                                                                            
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor                                                                                                                                      
executor = SequentialExecutor                                                                                                                                                            

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.                                                                                                                             
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information                                                                                                                   
# their website                                                                                                                                                                          
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/ikar/airflow/airflow.db

# The SqlAlchemy pool size is the maximum number of database connections
# in the pool.
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5

# The SqlAlchemy pool recycle is the number of seconds a connection
# can be idle in the pool before it is invalidated. This config does
# not apply to sqlite.
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600

# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool",
# whose size is guided by this config element
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16

# Whether to load the examples that ship with Airflow. It's good to
# get started, but you probably want to set this to False in a production
# environment
load_examples = False

# Where your Airflow plugins are stored
plugins_folder = /home/ikar/airflow/plugins

# Secret key to save connection passwords in the db
fernet_key = cryptography_not_found_storing_passwords_in_plain_text

# Whether to disable pickling dags
donot_pickle = False

# How long before timing out a python file import while filling the DagBag
dagbag_import_timeout = 30

# The class to use for running task instances in a subprocess
task_runner = BashTaskRunner

# If set, tasks without a `run_as_user` argument will be run with this user
# Can be used to de-elevate a sudo user running Airflow when executing tasks
default_impersonation =

# What security module to use (for example kerberos):
security =

# Turn unit test mode on (overwrites many configuration options with test
# values at runtime)
unit_test_mode = False

[cli]
# In what way should the cli access the API. The LocalClient will use the
# database directly, while the json_client will use the api running on the
# webserver
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8888

[api]
# How to authenticate users of the API
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

[operators]
# The default owner assigned to each new operator, unless
# provided explicitly or passed via `default_args`
default_owner = Airflow
default_cpus = 1
default_ram = 512
default_disk = 512
default_gpus = 0


[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
base_url = http://localhost:8888

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8888

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 30

# Secret key used to run your flask app
secret_key = temporary_key

# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4

# The worker class gunicorn should use. Choices include
# sync (default), eventlet, gevent
worker_class = sync

# Log files for the gunicorn webserver. '-' means log to stderr.
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -

# Expose the configuration file in the web server
expose_config = False

# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth

# Filter the list of dags by owner name (requires authentication to be enabled)
filter_by_owner = True

# Filtering mode. Choices include user (default) and ldapgroup.
# Ldap group filtering requires using the ldap backend
#
# Note that the ldap server needs the "memberOf" overlay to be set up
# in order to user the ldapgroup mode.
owner_mode = user

# Default DAG orientation. Valid values are:
# LR (Left->Right), TB (Top->Bottom), RL (Right->Left), BT (Bottom->Top)
dag_orientation = LR

# Puts the webserver in demonstration mode; blurs the names of Operators for
# privacy.
demo_mode = False

# The amount of time (in secs) webserver will wait for the initial handshake
# while fetching logs from another worker machine
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5

# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False

[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
# smtp_user = airflow
# smtp_password = airflow
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow@airflow.com


[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
celeryd_concurrency = 4

# When you start an airflow worker, airflow starts a tiny web server
# subprocess to serve the workers local log files to the airflow main
# web server, who then builds pages and sends them to users. This defines
# the port on which the logs are served. It needs to be unused, and open
# visible from the main web server to connect into the workers.
worker_log_server_port = 8793

# The Celery broker URL. Celery supports RabbitMQ, Redis and experimentally
# a sqlalchemy database. Refer to the Celery documentation for more
# information.
broker_url = sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow

# Another key Celery setting
celery_result_backend = db+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow

# Celery Flower is a sweet UI for Celery. Airflow has a shortcut to start
# it `airflow flower`. This defines the IP that Celery Flower runs on
flower_host = 0.0.0.0

# This defines the port that Celery Flower runs on
flower_port = 5555

# Default queue that tasks get assigned to and that worker listens on.
default_queue = default


[scheduler]
# Task instances listen for external kill signal (when you clear tasks
# from the CLI or the UI), this defines the frequency at which they should
# listen (in seconds).
job_heartbeat_sec = 5

# The schedule constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5

# after how much time should the scheduler terminate in seconds
# -1 indicates to run continuously (see also num_runs)
run_duration = -1

# after how much time a new DAGs should be picked up from the filesystem
min_file_process_interval = 0

dag_dir_list_interval = 300

# How often should stats be printed to the logs
print_stats_interval = 30

child_process_log_directory = /home/ikar/airflow/logs/scheduler

# Local task jobs periodically heartbeat to the DB. If the job has
# not heartbeat in this many seconds, the scheduler will mark the
# associated task instance as failed and will re-schedule the task.
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300

# Turn off scheduler catchup by setting this to False.
# Default behavior is unchanged and
# Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler
# will not do scheduler catchup if this is False,
# however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the
# DAG definition (catchup)
catchup_by_default = False

# Statsd (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow

# The scheduler can run multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags.
# This defines how many threads will run. However, airflow will never
# use more threads than the number of cpu cores available.
max_threads = 2

authenticate = False


[mesos]
# Mesos master address which MesosExecutor will connect to.
master = localhost:5050

# The framework name which Airflow scheduler will register itself as on mesos
framework_name = Airflow

# Number of cpu cores required for running one task instance using
# 'airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -p <pickle_id>'
# command on a mesos slave
task_cpu = 1

# Memory in MB required for running one task instance using
# 'airflow run <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date> --local -p <pickle_id>'
# command on a mesos slave
task_memory = 256

# Enable framework checkpointing for mesos
# See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/slave-recovery/
checkpoint = False

# Failover timeout in milliseconds.
# When checkpointing is enabled and this option is set, Mesos waits
# until the configured timeout for
# the MesosExecutor framework to re-register after a failover. Mesos
# shuts down running tasks if the
# MesosExecutor framework fails to re-register within this timeframe.
# failover_timeout = 604800

# Enable framework authentication for mesos
# See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/
authenticate = False

# Mesos credentials, if authentication is enabled
# default_principal = admin
# default_secret = admin


[kerberos]
ccache = /tmp/airflow_krb5_ccache
# gets augmented with fqdn
principal = airflow
reinit_frequency = 3600
kinit_path = kinit
keytab = airflow.keytab


[github_enterprise]
api_rev = v3


[admin]
# UI to hide sensitive variable fields when set to True
hide_sensitive_variable_fields = True
```

I'd expect that `test` user will only see DAG with the owner set to `test` but both users can see and execute both DAGs.

Couldn't find any detailed documentation on how to setup the user restrictions for airflow DAGs.

Can anyone help? Am I missing something?

Comment: created an issue in apache airflow jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1856

Comment: We're having an exactly same issue. Haven't found any workarounds yet.

Answer (score 0):

this error is solved in airflow 1.10.5, you can check the changelog
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6fb821713fe0185b4af3a17d008a04a7669a3a64/CHANGELOG.txt#L932

Comment: Please add the part of the log that states the fix, in case the URL changes etc.