# How to use the User role in Airflow 1.10 RBAC?

Tags: airflow, rbac

I have been trying to look at how to use the `User` role. It says [here](https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/improving-airflow-ui-security), that it is for users with DAG ownership. So I created a couple of users with usernames `ABC` and `XYZ` and assigned them with `User` role.

Here's my DAG:

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'ABC',
    ...,
    ...
}

dag = DAG(
    'test_dag',
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    ...,
    ...
)
```

When I logged in as `XYZ`, I expected the DAG `test_dag` to be hidden. If not hidden then at least to be in inactive state, since `test_dag` belongs to `ABC`. But as a `XYZ`, I'm able to operate `test_dag`.

Am I missing anything out here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the new RBAC UI. Verify that you have the following in your `airflow.cfg` file

```
[webserver]
rbac = True
authenticate = True
filter_by_owner = True
```

Comment: Yes, I already have that set. _Make sure you are using the new RBAC UI._ -- I am using 1.10 which has RBAC. Is there a newer UI after that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using password authentication? If so, this is probably a bug, that is still not fixed: [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1856). It was also discussed here: [How to allow airflow dags for concrete user(s) only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393411/how-to-allow-airflow-dags-for-concrete-users-only)

You can try to use LDAP or OAuth as you authentication method. This might resolve your problem.